# Method linking/anchoring in Java

Tags: java, eclipse

I created several Java methods that indirectly related. Question is, can I create some hyperlink between those methods as reference?
I am using Eclipse for Java IDE.

Comment: What do you mean by "hyperlink"?  Are you talking about the Javadocs?

Comment: Or are you looking for a way to jump between them? If so, you might want to look at context-clicking the margin of a line and adding a bookmark. Or you might want to use the Alt+left / Alt+right keys to jump back and forward. Or you might find where the other methods are invoked and press F3 to jump to them.

Comment: Yes, All this time i just comment on every method to create some reference. I think it will be easier to just click on certain text and send your screen to destination method, rather than CTRL+F.

Comment: @Knight You can do exactly that; click on some text and send your screen to that class/method. Just hold Ctrl while clicking on that text (also posted that as part of my answer).

Comment: Yes I can do that, but only if I use/call the reference method inside a referenced method. Well, its been answered, thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the JavaDoc @see tag:

```
/**
 * @see MyClass#myMethod()
 */
```

This generates a hyperlink in your JavaDoc.

Comment: Well, thank you sir, it works :) My Coding life will be easier.

Answer (score 2):

In Eclipse, code completion also works in comments and can be used to create links. When you start typing the name of a class, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> to get a list of matching classes. It will create an `@link` tag for that class. Adding a `#` behind the name and repeating the autocompletion shortcut gives you a list of methods of that class. For methods of the same class you are working in, just type `#` and hit auto completion.

Clicking on a class or method name in the comment while holding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> will let you jump to that class or method, even without the `@see` or `@link` tags.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend the [`@see`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/tooldocs/windows/javadoc.html#@see) Javadoc tag; other than that (and the previously-mentioned, but IMO less semantically meaningful `@link` tag), not really.

Answer (score 0):

As others pointed out, your question could stand some clarification.  If you don't mean JavaDoc, but you mean somehow relate the classes together even though they have no common interface, you can use a [marker interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marker_interface_pattern), which is an interface with no methods.  It's so called because it adds a marker to the classes, and you can test whether a class implements the interface.