# Writing a comment in Eclipse linking a specific line

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, code-formatting

i'm working with Eclipse in Java and with long long classes i need a feature like this: in the top comment of a method (for example) there is a list of operations executed by the method.
For each operation listed, i'd like to "hyperlink" a portion of the comment to a specific line of the related code.

Then using Ctrl+Click to that line i can jump directly to the specified line code.

Is it possible an operation like this?

Thanks

Comment: I am pretty sure you can only link to methods (e.g. the ones you call) not to code inside of methods.

Comment: 'a list of operations' sounds a little if each 'operation' is a candidate for *extract to method* refactoring. Why would you want to make comments in the method-comment related to implementation specific decisions within the method (They might change without changing the functionality of the method)?

Comment: @MrSmith42 you are right, i can use different methods but, as kw4nta is saying, how can i link methods?

Comment: Why don't you bookmark these lines?

Answer (score 7):

In the comment below your question you say:

> how can i link methods?

Take a look at the following example: you can press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + click on `bar()` within the JavaDoc of `foo()` and eclipse jumps to the method `bar()`.

```
public class Example {

    /**
     * JavaDoc of foo(). This method executes {@link Example#bar()}
     */
    public void foo() {
        bar();
    }

    /**
     * Javadoc of bar().
     */
    public void bar() { }
}
```

Eclipse even offers autocomplete for `@link`, the classname and the method (after you manually entered the `#`).

Is that what you are looking for?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the JavaDoc @see tag:

```
/**
* @see MyClass#myMethod()
*/
```

This generates a hyperlink in your JavaDoc.

SRC: [method-linking-anchoring-in-java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7402499/method-linking-anchoring-in-java)

Comment: Works only on *method*-level. You cannot link to parts within the method. That was the question.

Comment: With this notation the links are shown only in JavaDoc. I need to use that links direcly on the code sources, like Ctrl+Click

Comment: In that case you can use some hyper link manager with eclipse see http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fjface%2Ftext%2Fhyperlink%2FHyperlinkManager.html

Answer (score 0):

The Eclipse IDE allows you to go from a method call to the method's definition ('F3' I think).

Apart from that, I don't think there's a way to set up "special" navigation.  Mind you, if you need something like that, it is a strong indication that your methods are WAY too large.  Refactor them.

---

Thinking outside of the box, if you were to feed your code through a code-to-html pretty printer, you could embed HTML hyperlinks and anchors in comments (javadoc or normal).  With a bit of luck, they would be clickable when you viewed the HTML-ized source code in a web browser.

---

Of course, Eclipse can follow javadoc "links".  Obviously the standard tags can't link to deep inside a method, but I guess you could write an Eclipse plugin that supported non-standard javadoc tags for linking to embedded anchors, and the navigation thereof.