# In Eclipse, how do I link to a line within a comment?

Tags: java, eclipse, hyperlink

I'm trying to explain why I placed a SuppressWarnings in my code, but since it appears that I can only place those above my method, I want to make a link to a specific line number within my comment. I thought that using `(<filename>.java:<line>)` would do the thing, but instead it just tells me about the file in question, not the actual contents of the line I want.

For example:

```
11 | @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") //I tend not to suppress warnings, but (Items.java:22) has no solution.
```

When I hover to or click on the `(Items.java:22)` part, it should take me to line 22:

```
22 | return (T) itemMap.get(name);
```

What do I have to do in order to make a link to the desired line in Eclipse? It doesn't have to be a specific line number since of course, when I start editing my code, the line I want to link to has already moved somewhere else. It could link to some kind of anchor (although I don't expect Eclipse to have such a complex linking feature set anytime soon).

Comment: This really doesn't sound that useful.  Almost any change to your code (adding/removing lines) will render that comment out-of-date, and thus useless.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Thanks for your opinion on the matter. I edited the question to address this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Writing a comment in Eclipse linking a specific line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15001432/writing-a-comment-in-eclipse-linking-a-specific-line)

Comment: @Leo - this doesn't really answer the question because the answer only refers to linking to methods, not explicit lines or anchors.

Comment: You'd have to write an Eclipse plugin. That aside, if a method is so big that a simple comment saying what it's for isn't enough, there are other issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ctrl + click on the `(<filename>.java:<line>)` comment works for me.